# Lower bound on gap between consecutive eigenvalues on $L_2(\mathbb{R}^3)$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

*[A similar version of this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/269591/minimum-gap-between-consecutive-energy-levels) was originally posted by me in [the physics community](http://physics.stackechange.com), but it was suggested that I ask the mathematicians instead. So I have tried to strip off most of the physics jargon and brush up my functional analysis-fu.*

Consider the stationary Schrödinger equation on $L_2(\mathbb{R}^3)$:
\begin{equation}
-\nabla^2\psi(\vec r)+V(\vec r)\psi(\vec r) = E\psi(\vec r)\text.
\end{equation}
Here $V(\vec r)$ can be assumed to be a sufficiently well-behaved function that vanishes at infinity. Assume this operator has a discrete spectrum and denote the discrete eigenvalues as $E_{n,\tau}$, where $n$ is the principal quantum number and $\tau$ represents all the other quantum numbers, if any.

**For a given $V(\vec r)$, is it possible to derive a lower bound on $E_{n+1,\tau}-E_{n,\tau}$, i.e. on the energy gap between consecutive levels with the same additional quantum numbers?** Physical intuition tells me that long-range potentials should allow smaller gaps (cf. the Coulomb potential $V(r)=1/r$, which yields $E_n\propto 1/n^2$, with the gap getting infinitely small as $n\to\infty$), but I haven't managed to express this quantitatively.

Comment: [related](http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2011-24-03/S0894-0347-2011-00699-1/S0894-0347-2011-00699-1.pdf)

Comment: Specific bounds in this generality is way too much to hope for. There has been much work though on related questions (for example, when is the discrete negative spectrum infinite?).